# Three.js adding box to scene not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, three.js

I'm trying to get Three.js to add a box to the scene on iOS but it doesn't seem to work while on macOS Safari it does.

The scene sets up correctly and adds the first box but when adding the "cube" it doesn't appear on the scene

iOS 12.1.1 on an iPad

```js
var scene, renderer, controls, camera;

function init() {
  container = document.getElementById("canvas");
  container.height = $("#canvas").height();
  container.width = $("#canvas").width();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(20, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(300, 300, 300);
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xfffff0);
  scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555));
  var light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
  light.position.set(0, 500, 2000);
  scene.add(light);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true,
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setClearColor(0xE6EEF2);
  renderer.setSize($(container).width(), $(container).height());
  renderer.sortObjects = false;
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.enableKeys = false;
  controls.enabled = false;
}

function addBox() {
  var orientation = {
    dim1: 78,
    dim2: 62,
    dim3: 35
  }
  var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(orientation.dim1, orientation.dim2, orientation.dim3);
  geom.translate(orientation.dim1 / 2, orientation.dim2 / 2, orientation.dim3 / 2);
  box_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0,
    alphaTest: 0.5
  });
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, box_material)
  var geometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(mesh.geometry);
  var edges_material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000,
    linewidth: 2
  });
  var edges = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, edges_material);
  mesh.name = "box1"
  scene.add(mesh.add(edges));
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function addCube() {
  pos = {
    x: 46,
    y: 0,
    z: 0
  };
  orientation = orientation = {
    dim1: 46,
    dim2: 28,
    dim3: 30
  }
  var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(orientation.dim1, orientation.dim2, orientation.dim3);
  geom.translate(pos.x + orientation.dim1 / 2, pos.y + orientation.dim2 / 2, pos.z + orientation.dim3 / 2);
  material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: Math.random() * 0xffffff,
    flatShading: true,
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.7
  });
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material)
  mesh.name = "cube";
  scene.add(mesh);
  console.log("added cube");
}

init();
animate();
addBox();
addCube();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-left: 1px solid #CED4D9;
  border-right: 1px solid #CED4D9;
  align-items: center;
}

.boxView-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/99/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>


<body>
  hello2
  <div id="root">
    <main class="main">
      <section class="content">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="boxView-container" id="canvas"></div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

On macOS Safari:
[image]

On iOS Safari:
[image]

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/acrogenesis/d583wyft/44/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is caused by variable scope. You need define some local variables, or else the addCube function will change some global variables above.

like var pos, mesh etc.

```
function addCube() {
    var pos = {x: 46, y: 0, z: 0};
    var orientation = {
        dim1: 46,
        dim2: 28,
        dim3: 30
    }
    var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(orientation.dim1, orientation.dim2,                         orientation.dim3);
    geom.translate(pos.x + orientation.dim1 / 2, pos.y + orientation.dim2 / 2, pos.z +         orientation.dim3 / 2);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: Math.random() * 0xffffff,
        flatShading: true,
        vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.7
    });
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material)
    mesh.name = "cube";
    scene.add(mesh);
    console.log("added cube");
}
```

After define these local variables, now working great on iOS.